# How to use Hadoop API copyMerge function? What is the addString parameter?

Tags: hadoop

Does anyone know or have used copyMerge function in Hadoop API - FileUtil?

```
copyMerge(FileSystem srcFS, Path srcDir, FileSystem dstFS, Path dstFile, boolean deleteSource, Configuration conf, String addString);
```

In the function, what is the addString parameter? How do I set how those files are merged? Example I have part number 1,2,3,4,5..., I want to combine them into one file in ascending order, how can I do it?

Detail about the API: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop-0.20.2+320/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can sue a function. That'll probably get thrown out of the courts very quickly.

Comment: @Peter O. You're no fun.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the the addString is just written to the OutputStream in the [FileUtil](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.2/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java) class

```
if (addString!=null)
    out.write(addString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

When there is no documentation, source code is the true and best source for details. I have written a few articles on how to setup Git [here](http://hadoop-tips.blogspot.com/2011/09/viewing-hadoop-code-in-git.html) and [here](http://hadoop-tips.blogspot.com/2011/09/qgit-gui-for-git.html). [Git](http://git-scm.com/) helps for faster and easier access to the code.